# Setting index as key in React should break UI but it does not

Tags: reactjs

I have a small React app that renders an array of image URL strings into `<img>` elements, and removes them when the image URL is broken. The broken URL can happen at any point in the array, which means it doesn't satisfy the conditions listed in [Robin Pokorny's article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) about when it is safe to use an array index as a React key:

> 1. the list and items are static–they are not computed and do not
>    change <-- NOT true since any `<img>` list item could be removed due to error
> 2. the items in the list have no ids
> 3. the list is never reordered or filtered

Theoretically, this means that if I did try to use the index as the key when creating JSX components like so:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div id="list">
        {this.state.urls.map((url, idx) => (
          // setting array index as the key, an anti-pattern
          <img key={`${idx}`} src={url} onError={this.handleError} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

then my understanding was that the virtual DOM node would not be diffed correctly, and the `src` attributes for each list item would not be updated correctly since React would not recognize that the `<img>` with key index 3 (for example) now has a new `src` value due to a broken URL at a index 2 being removed.

In short, am I misunderstanding something about how React uses keys in its reconciliation algorithm?

NOTE: just to confirm, I am not mutating state in the handleError function, so I don't think that's contributing:

```js
handleError(e) {
    const url = e.target.src;
    const newUrls = [...this.state.urls];
    newUrls.splice(newUrls.indexOf(url), 1);
    this.setState({ urls: newUrls });
  }
```

Comment: I have a feeling that someone, long time ago, said that using `index` as the key is an anti-pattern and everyone sticks to it, but no one knows actually why. As long as you dont change order of the mapped items, using `index` is okey.

Comment: @kinduser That's what I thought too, but does removing elements arbitrarily in the middle of the list of items not count as "changing the order"?

Comment: I believe removing particular item in a middle of mapped elements is an order change and you should probably avoid `index`, but Im not like 100% sure. Maybe someone more clever than me could confirm.

Comment: Yes, it is an order change. If you have `[A,B,C]` and remove `B`, index `1` will represent `C` instead of `B`. So you are using the same key to represent different elements.

Comment: For your particular case it is working fine, because you passing down props, and src prop changed so react does re-render second img successfully. The problems are happening when your inner component (img for example) uses some state, instead of prop, so in prop you would have only key, so react would think "nothing has changed there - don't need to check"

Comment: @NikitaChayka Oh so regardless of whether the keys are the same, React will still update the attribute values! I think I assumed that if they key is the same React would just ignore the rest of the diffing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Misusing (or not using) keys *can* break UI and it definitely will with DOM elements that have state (such as inputs) that is not managed by React.

However, with elements that are fully managed by React, misusing keys will just cause unnecessary DOM changes; for instance, if you have a list `["cat.jpg", "dog.jpg"]` and you swap the two with list indices as keys, React will have to set the `src`s for two elements; otherwise it could just swap the nodes' orders within the DOM without setting `src`s.

Comment: Super useful example to illustrate the updates, thank you!